# How to override Authorize attribute for a specific page which is used in _Imports.razor in blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In blazor WASM I have applied an Authorize attribute with a policy in root _Imports.razor file.

`@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "ValidPackageAndEmailVerification")]`

Now for a specific routable page, I want not to use this Policy and instead want to use a simple Authorize attribute, to check if a user is logged in or not.

`@attribute [Authorize]`

I have applied the `@attribute [Authorize]` attribute to my page thinking that it may override the authorize attribute in _Imports.razor file, but it does not.

is there any way to achieve this?

One solution I think of is to have separate _Imports.razor file in each module folder instead of root _Imports.razor file, but I think there should be another way.

Comment: You can't. If you want to use imports.razor like this put your Auth pages in one folder and the others in another. Put a _Imports razor in the one using the policy. Move your @attrubute statement to that _imports.razor in the folder.